# Jython caches values when accessed via a service

Tags: jython

I have two python files. One with name Test.py. This calls a method get_values() from getList.py file

```html
#Test.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/data/")
import getList
import json
final_list = getList.get_values()
print json.dumps(final_list)
```

```html
#getList.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,/data/pymongo/)
import pymongo
from pymongo import Connection


def get_values():
 final_list = list()
 connection = Connection('localhost', 5000)
 db = connection.testScript
 collection = db.scriptCache
 for post in collection.find({},{"author":1,"_id":0}):
         final_list.append(post)
 return final_list
```

I am executing the file Test.py from java using jython with the following code:

```html
public void executeScript(String inputFile, String outputFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
  final PythonInterpreter inter = new PythonInterpreter();
  Writer writer = null;
  writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new    FileOutputStream(outputFile)));
  inter.setOut(writer);
  inter.execfile(inputFile);
 }
```

The mongo document structure is :
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54e6e9338c27b9a4542b1499"), "name" : "Python", "author" : "James" }

In  getList.py I am querying "author" for the first time. If i execute Test.py, it returns correct result.

Later I am editing getList.py to query "name" and executing Test.py but I am getting the same result that is "author".

The problem occurs only when executing the java class via a service. If I execute the same via a standalone program it's working fine.

Is there any property need to configure to avoid such caching?

Answer (score 0):

Python caches the results of getList when called for a first time and returns the same value when accessed again.

To execute the getList.py every time we execute Test.py, we need to reload getList.py.

Inclusion of below line (reload) solved the issue.

import getList

reload(getList)